# How are the gain and corner frequencies calculated for this speech bandpass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, gain

This speech bandpass filter circuit appears in the [TI OPA344 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa344.pdf).  It says "G = 100" and passband is 300 Hz to 3 kHz.  How is the gain and corner frequencies calculated from the various component values?  I'd like to try this circuit but I only need a gain of 5 and I might want to tweak the passband.

[image: Speech Bandpass Filter]

I think I see that R7 and C2 form a first order low pass filter with a corner frequency of 3120 Hz.  And I believe R6 and R5 produce a gain of (1 + R6/R5) = 6.  But I don't understand the rest of the circuit.  Where is the rest of the gain and the high pass filter?

Comment: By initial inspection the gain seems to me to be 50, not 100.  To calculate the transfer function start with 6*Vin at the left side of R7, and Vin at the right side of R8.  Write KCL at the junction of R7 + R8, then use the voltage across C3 to get another expression linking Vout to the voltage on C2 and solve the whole mess for Vo/Vin.

Comment: Brian is correct, I overlooked R4 when I first glanced at the circuit, pretty close to a gain of 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main part of the filter (sectioned in red below) is a modified MFLP filter and not a Sallen-key filter: -

[image]

I've used [Mr. Okawa's](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php) web site for doing the analysis and it tells me that the cut-off frequency is about 3.2kHz and there should be no peaking because the Q (or damping ratio if you did the math) is about optimum for flat response (\$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$).

The high pass stage is at the input with C1 and R2//R3. This works out at 318 Hz for it's 3dB point.

One slight modification to the general type of circuit is the 2nd op-amp (that forms the MFLP filter) receives mid-rail bias from R2 and R3 but also a smidgin' of input signal. This doesn't alter the frequency response too much but does subtract 1 from the calculated gain of the 2nd stage. Okawa calculated it at 10 when I believe, with the modification it will be 9. The first op-amp stage gain is 11 and the total gain (at mid-frequency)  will be 99 and not 100!

Comment: Thank you.  I mistakenly ignored C1, R2, and R3 because I've seen that repeatedly (as a coupling capacitor and setting the mid-rail voltage) in other electret mic preamp circuits.  But now I see that it is also a high pass filter.  And the MFLP is new to me.